# Convert VBA unmerge and fil to VBscript unmerge and fill

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

Hello I am trying to convert VBA to VBscript but having trouble as I do not know where to start. Any help is appreciated.

**VBA:** Un-merging cells and then filling data to those cells from original merged data cell.

```
Sub UnMergeFill()

Dim cell As Range, joinedCells As Range

For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If cell.MergeCells Then
        Set joinedCells = cell.MergeArea
        cell.MergeCells = False
        joinedCells.Value = cell.Value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

**VBScript:** I have the start of the code to open the correct excel file and save and close but not the modification the VBA script is doing.

```
'create the excel object
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

'view the excel program and file, set to false to hide the whole process
    objExcel.Visible = True 

'open an excel file (make sure to change the location) .xls for 2003 or earlier
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\vbsTest.xlsx")

'save the existing excel file
    objWorkbook.Save

'close the workbook
    objWorkbook.Close 

'exit the excel program
    objExcel.Quit

'release objects
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    Set objWorkbook = Nothing
```

Comment: You just have to replace ThisWorkbook with objWorkbook.

Answer (score 0):

VBscript Code:

```
'Microsoft Excel Automation
':: Open, unmerge cells and fill then save
'---------------------------------
'create the excel object
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

'view the excel program and file, set to false to hide the whole process
    objExcel.Visible = True 

'open an excel file (make sure to change the location) .xls for 2003 or earlier
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Book3.xlsx")

Dim cell
Dim joinedCells

For Each cell In objWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If cell.MergeCells Then
        Set joinedCells = cell.MergeArea
        cell.MergeCells = False
        joinedCells.Value = cell.Value
    End If
Next

'save the existing excel file
    objWorkbook.Save

'close the workbook
    objWorkbook.Close 

'exit the excel program
    objExcel.Quit

'release objects
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    Set objWorkbook = Nothing
```